# watermelonDB setting a relation field throws : Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

Tags: react-native, watermelondb

I have two tables, 'users' and 'clubs,' that are related with a **one-to-many** relation. This means each user can be associated with many clubs, and each club is owned by one user. However, when attempting to create a new club and set its user to the current user record, an error is encountered: **'Cannot read property 'set' of undefined.'**.

#### The piece of code that throws the error:

```
@writer async addClub(name, location) {
    const newClub = await this.collections.get('clubs').create( club => {
      club.user.set(this) // <= this throws "Cannot read property 'set' of undefined"
      club.name = name
      club.location =location
    })
    return newClub
  }
```

#### Models :

```
class User extends Model {
    static table = 'users';
    static associations = {
        clubs: { type: 'has_many', foreignKey: 'user_id' },
     }     
    @text('email') email;
    @field('password') password;
    @text('first_name') firstName;
    @text('last_name') lastName;a
    @text('username') username;
    @readonly @date('created_at') createdAt;
    @field('is_active') isActive;
    @field('is_deleted') isDeleted;
    @field('is_admin') isAdmin;
    @field('is_onboarded') isOnboarded;
    @children('clubs') clubs;

    @writer async addClub(name, location) {
      const newClub = await this.collections.get('clubs').create( club => {
        club.user.set(this)
        club.name = name
        club.location =location
      })
      return newClub
    } 
}
```

```
class Club extends Model {
    static table = 'clubs';
    static associations = {
        users: { type: 'belongs_to', key: 'user_id' },
        groups: { type: 'has_many', foreignKey: 'club_id' },
      }
    @text('name') name;
    @text('location') location;
    @text('logo') logo;
    @readonly @date('created_at') createdAt;
    @readonly @date('updated_at') updatedAt;
    @field('is_active') isActive;
    @field('is_deleted') isDeleted;
    @relation('users', 'user_id') user;
    @children('groups') groups;
 }
```

#### List of dependencies for this project:

```
"react-native": "0.72.7",
"@nozbe/watermelondb": "^0.27.1",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.23.3",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
```

#### Babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    ["module:react-native-dotenv", 
      {
        "moduleName": "@env",
        "path": ".env",
        "blacklist": null,
        "whitelist": null,
        "safe": false,
        "allowUndefined": true
      }
    ],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "version": "legacy" }],
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin'
  ],
};
```